# Android Unable to instantiate activity: Didn't find class on path

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, android-activity

I've imported project into eclipse and when I try to run it, then this exception is thrown:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.polygraf/com.polygraf.activity.Dashboard}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.polygraf.activity.Dashboard" on path: /data/app/com.polygraf-1.apk`

I've tried to clean the project, then check if all class names and manifest are ok, but still can't find why this happens. Can you help me a little please?

Dashbard class:

```
public class Dashboard extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String WELCOME_TYPE = "WELCOME_TYPE";
private static final String HELP_TYPE = "HELP_TYPE";

public static final String ADRESS_CONTENT = "ADRESS_CONTENT";
public static final String DOC_NAME = "DOC_NAME";

private Transcript mContent;
private ISettableContent mListOfDocument;

private String mAddress;

private String mDocName;

public Dashboard() {
}

/** Called with the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

    boolean content = false;
    // View gc = (NoSaveStateFrameLayout)
    // findViewById(R.id.content_fragment);
    //

    Fragment frContent = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_fragment);
    mContent = ((IGetContent) frContent).getContent();
    TranscriptSetting cc = Polygraf.getInstance().getContentSetting();

    Fragment frDocumentsList = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.documents);
    mListOfDocument = (ISettableContent) frDocumentsList;
    cc.registerContent(mListOfDocument);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra(ADRESS_CONTENT)) {
        mAddress = getIntent().getStringExtra(ADRESS_CONTENT);
        mDocName = getIntent().getStringExtra(DOC_NAME);
        mContent.setAddress(mAddress, mDocName);
        content = true;
    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra(WELCOME_TYPE)) {
        content = true;
        prepareVisibilityBtnTranscript();
    } else if (getIntent().hasExtra(HELP_TYPE)) {
        content = true;
        mContent.showHelp();

    }

    if (content) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.hide(frDocumentsList);
        ft.commit();

        // because on diferent layouts for small and large device
        // some views missing, so the test is inportant
        View contentLayout = findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
        if (contentLayout != null) {
            contentLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        prepareVisibilityBtnWelcome();
        // cp.setContent(mContent);
    }

    cc.registerContent(mContent);
    // cp.setListener(cc);

}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:name=".Polygraf"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/skeleton_app"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.polygraf.activity.Dashboard"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <!-- This places this activity into the main app list. -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.polygraf.activity.SettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/skeleton_app" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.polygraf.activity.ContentActivity"
        android:label="@string/skeleton_app" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.polygraf.activity.PlayVideo"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:label="@string/skeleton_app" />
</application>
```

Comment: Do you reference any class or jars etc in your proj ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suppose you're using Eclipse. Your activity is there alright, but Eclipse didn't include the support package in the APK ... If you look above your error in stacktrace you will notice the root of your problem: "`Unable to find FragmentActivity`". Or you can unpack the apk, undex it and you will see the compatibility package classes were not included.

To fix this, right-click your project, properties, build path and go to export tab. There make sure "`Android private libraries`" are checked. A clean and rebuild should put you on track ...

Comment: Yup, that was it. It happened because of I yesterday updated ADT plugin to 22.0.1 which also caused that none of my other apps are buildable. Issue was exactly what you've mentioned (also found in http://undefinedvalue.com/2013/05/29/android-sdk-tools-2201-considered-harmful article). If anyone tries that be sure that you will clean the project afterwards :) Thanks

Comment: What a great help. Almost forgot the nuances of Eclipse!

Comment: @gunar can you tell me the solution for android studio?

Answer (score 2):

After i spend a while on this problem, the solution that i found is a conflict between importing Properties > Android  - appcompat_v7 and appcompat_v4 that was added in the libs folder. After i remove the appcompat_v4 the error no longer appear.
I hope that answer can help in the future someone.

Answer (score 0):

You should import new appcompat_v7 from sdk and use it as a built path,it works for me.