# Android: Unable to instantiate activity though the class is present and referenced correctly in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I get the following exception when I right click and run an android project from eclipse:

```
09-25 13:32:07.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 13:32:07.928: E/AndroidRuntime(23103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity   ComponentInfo{com.nykkos.personalize/com.nykkos.personalize.profiler.Personalization}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nykkos.personalize.profiler.Personalization
```

I have re-confirmed that the class exists. For reference, I am pasting relevant code of manifest here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.nykkos.personalize"
android:sharedUserId="com.googlecheckout"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/amigo_logo1"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".profiler.Personalization"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have no idea as to why this error is shown, though the class mentioned in the exception is present in my code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to clean, rebuild and run. Check the Console to make sure the new app is installed.

Comment: try it with  android:name=".Personalization" or  android:name="com.nykkos.personalize.profiler.Personalization"

Comment: Maybe it's because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17273328/1051783).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with

android:name=".Personalization" or       android:name="com.nykkos.personalize.profiler.Personalization"

Comment: android:name="com.nykkos.personalize.profiler.Personalization" . It worked , wondering why it works perfect from a different machine and only with this fix in another!!