# Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.fragment When running on Android 2.2

Tags: android, fragment, android-2.2-froyo, drawerlayout

I want to add support for my app to the Android Foryo.

But I cannot seem to figure the problem out. I have done many research using Google and in StackOverflow. The only thing I got is that I have to use `<android.support.v4.app.fragment` instead of `<fragment` using the support library, but that is also doesn't work!

Whenever I try to run the application it crushes and I get this error in the LogCat.

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.fragment`

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/settings_fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FFffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <android.support.v4.app.fragment
            android:id="@+id/settings_fragment_section"
            android:name="com.example.SettingsFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Java**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.example;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author 
 * 
 */

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**SettingsFragment.java**
*It's just...*

```
package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.nozzha.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_settings);
    }

}
```

**LogCat**

```
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.fragment
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #40: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.fragment
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     ... 11 more
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: fragment(Context,AttributeSet)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
11-22 11:19:54.141: E/AndroidRuntime(1197):     ... 22 more
```

Comment: can you post SettingsFragment class?

Comment: include code for `SettingsFragment.java` also.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code of SettingsFragment.java

Comment: Did you include the compatibility package in the exported tab? As [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273218/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-didnt-find-class-on-path/17273328#17273328)

Comment: @gunar Yes, and I made sure!

Comment: Have you check out the support library's demo code? As i found out in samples the declaration is something like <fragment class="com.example.android.supportv4.app.FragmentLayoutSupport$TitlesFragment" . though i haven't tested it in android 2.2 you can try like this.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your Activity does not extend the base Activity `FragmentActivity`. If you use Support Based Fragment, then your Activity must extend the `FragmentActivity`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Answer (score 0):

please try adding the constructor.  public void SettingsFragment(){}.  Activity needs it to properly initialize the fragment.