# Upload Photo using HttpPost MultiPartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, httprequest

I am trying to upload the taken photo to server. this is what i do:

```
public JSONObject makePostFileRequest(String url, String photoFile) {
    try {
        // photoFile = /path/tofile/pic.jpg
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = GlobalData.httpClient;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        File file = new File(photoFile);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file); // here is line 221

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("PhotoMessage", fileBody);

        httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

I get this error:

> 11-29 13:12:14.924: E/AndroidRuntime(15781): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
>       11-29 13:12:14.924: E/AndroidRuntime(15781):  at  org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.(FileBody.java:89)
>       11-29 13:12:14.924: E/AndroidRuntime(15781):  at com.petcial.petopen.custom.JSONParser.makePostFileRequest(JSONParser.java:221)

What am I doing wrong?

---

Update

```
InputStream inputStream;
inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(photoFile));
byte[] data;
data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
                        System.getProperty("http.agent"));
InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "Pic.jpg");

MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
multipartEntity.addPart("PhotoMessage", inputStreamBody);

httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

here is the error:

> 11-29 14:00:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(19478): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.util.Args     11-29
>   14:00:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
>       11-29 14:00:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):  at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody.(InputStreamBody.java:69)
>     11-29 14:00:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at
>   org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody.(InputStreamBody.java:62)
>     11-29 14:00:33.364: E/AndroidRuntime(19478):    at
>   com.petcial.petopen.custom.JSONParser.makePostFileRequest(JSONParser.java:233)

these libraries solved my issue:

[image]

Comment: `FileBody` doesn't belong to standard Android library. What jar are you using?

Comment: have u added httpmime-4.3.jar in project?

Comment: of course. in the libs folder

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? If so, make sure it's added and exported, [as in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17273328/1051783)

Comment: Hi,  @FilipLuch have you find any solution for this issue?

Comment: yes. check out the last update of my question, and the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
Check that jar in Order and Export tab and run.

Answer (score 6):

There is my working solution for sending image with post, using apache http libraries (very important here is boundary add It won't work without it in my connection):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(StaticData.AMBAJE_SERVER_URL + StaticData.AMBAJE_ADD_AMBAJ_TO_GROUP);

String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(imageBytes, "pic.png");
StringBody sbOwner = new StringBody(StaticData.loggedUserId, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
StringBody sbGroup = new StringBody("group", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
                    .setBoundary(boundary)
                    .addPart("group", sbGroup)
                    .addPart("owner", sbOwner)
                    .addPart("image", bab)
                    .build();

httpPost.setEntity(entity);

try {
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
       ...then reading response
```

Comment: You saved me from losing another day!! I looked around Stackoverflow for hours and after adding the boundary it started working!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Better you pass the path of image file. Below is my code which I used to upload image to server.

```
public class UploadProductDetails {


    public void uploadProductDetails(String filePath, String fileName)
    {

        InputStream inputStream;
        try
        {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            byte[] data;
            try
            {
                data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                httpClient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,
                        System.getProperty("http.agent"));



                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ipaddress");


                InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "abc.png");
                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                multipartEntity.addPart("file", inputStreamBody);


                httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                // Handle response back from script.
                if(httpResponse != null) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Upload Completed. ", 2000).show();

                } else { // Error, no response.
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "Server Error. ", 2000).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to give your second answer or opinion then add this answer to your first answer and edit it..

Comment: i get error on The type `org.apache.http.entity.ContentType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files` on `InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), "abc.png");`

Comment: http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/  and

Comment: You can use these links to get your solution.

Comment: i added the required libs. but i still get same kind of error. what could be the issue? please check the updated question

Comment: See my above answer(image). I checked some libraries in Order and Expoet tab... That can be an issue...

Comment: i am still facing same error. and all examples i find are with `MultipartEntity` not `MultipartEntityBuilder` also i need to use HttpClient

Comment: i get "411 Length Required" when i attempt to upload my 2.8Mega Byte file using this code, any ideas why?

Comment: Hector: this long size image can cause OutOfMemoryException

Comment: better u reduce its size and then upload

Answer (score 0):

Note that using this code: `new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(yourByteArray))` might result in some problems, because it returns `-1` when calling `getContentLength()`.

Instead, use this: `new ByteArrayBody(yourByteArray)`