# what's the principle of uploading a file in android-async-http?

Tags: file-upload, android-async-http

I had a question when using android-async-http. After reading the source code, I knew about how to add a File or InputStream as a parameter into RequestParam. Then the RequestParam would be transferred into an AsyncHttpClient which would use RequestParam to get/put/post....Just like this:

```
String url = ...;
File file = ...;
ResponseHandlerInterface respHandler = ...;
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.add("upload_file", file);
client.get(url, params, respHandler);
```

As we all know, Files of any types are bits essentially. So when delivered over the internet, files could be transferred into a byte stream. But I didn't find any codes about this conversion. So, I wonder how android-async-http completes this, or did I miss something when reading source codes?

Comment: you may look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26210781/1761003)

Comment: @maveň, Sorry, I didn't think it resolved my question. Thank you all the same.

Comment: `What else you want to know?`

Comment: @maveň, how does android-async-http complete the conversion from file/inputstream to bytes stream before parameters are submitted to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I found the way android-async-http handled with files/inputstreams. Uploading a file depends on the call of `put(?)/post(?)`, but not `get(?)`. By searching the overwrited methods of `put(?)/post(?)`, you will find `paramsToEntity(RequestParams, ResponseHandlerInterface)` which will return a `HttpEntity`. And then, HttpPost/HttpPut will `setEntity(HttpEntity)`. Because `get(?)`s don't support uploading files, then you can't find operations about uploading files in `get(?)`s.