# Use HTTPURLConnection with MultiPartEntityBuilder

Tags: java, android, multipartentity

I am using following code snippet,

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity =  MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=");
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        try {
          //  reqEntity.writeTo(bos); which method shall I use instead of writeTo();
         } finally {
            bos.close();
            bos.flush();
        }
```

In `MultipartEntityBuilder`, there is no method called, writeTo(BufferedOutputStream bos), So instead of that which method shall I used to make it work?

NOTE:

```
MultipartEntity is deprecated now from Android api-level 23 and above.
```

Comment: This post may help you :
[Past question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210679/post-files-to-server-from-android-multipartentitybuilder-http)

Comment: @NikolayTomitov: thnx for post but `HTTPPost` is deprecated in Android-api lvl 23, thats why we are trying with `HTTPURLConnection` and we are not able to find the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the `HttpEntity` so

`ReqEntity.build().writeTo(<OutputStream>)`