# Error in doInBackground() -> NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType

Tags: java, android, apache, android-asynctask

I am uploading an image to server. There is some error in `Asynctask` while I do .addpart with the fileupload. I am new to this so please help me.
The variable filepath has some issues in `Asynctask` according to me.
My `manifest.xml` file has the required permissions.

```
public class UploadActivity extends Activity{
private String filePath = null;
private Button btnUpload;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    // Receiving the data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server
            new Upload().execute();
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
private class Upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.102/fileUpload.php");

           MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
           File sourceFile = new File(filePath);
            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));
            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}  
}
```

**Error log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
        at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
        at com.example.apurwa.camera.UploadActivity$Upload.uploadFile(UploadActivity.java:104)
        at com.example.apurwa.camera.UploadActivity$Upload.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:91)
        at com.example.apurwa.camera.UploadActivity$Upload.doInBackground(UploadActivity.java:83)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem most probably is that you are not importing `org.apache.http` library correctly. That's why your crash giving you `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

What you have to do is to make sure that you are importing the library correctly. So if you are using `Eclipse`, then download the JAR file form this [link](https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

If you are using `Android Studio`, then make sure of your dependencies in the `Gradle` file from this [link](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html)

Also have a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284542/upload-photo-using-httppost-multipartentitybuilder), it discusses similar issue to yours

Comment: I checked and mostly there is no dependency problem.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.util.Args
            at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.

Comment: No I'll try that now.

Answer (score 0):

Add library containing org.apache.http.entity.ContentType to build path.