# Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK Android Studio Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Am getting an unexpected error in Android studio while running the app,following is the error message which am getting

> Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK
>   /home/jithu/libs/android/android/aa/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk
>     Path in archive: META-INF/DEPENDENCIES  Origin 1:
>   /home/jithu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.3.6/cf8bacbf0d476c7f2221f861269365b66447f7ec/httpmime-4.3.6.jar
>     Origin 2:
>   /home/jithu/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.1/f5aa318bda4c6c8d688c9d00b90681dcd82ce636/httpcore-4.4.1.jar

Am pasting my build.gradle file also

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"


}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: remove `compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"` and try..

Comment: i did it,but that time its allows me to compile but giving following error
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
05-20 18:44:58.485: E/AndroidRuntime(395):  at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)

Comment: Probably duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673888/duplicate-files-copied-android-studio-0-4-0

Comment: @HareshChhelana you can see i already added that exclude statements.still its giving me the error,and am using the latest version of studio.

Comment: @MD if i remove the httpmime we will get following class miss errors
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
these are missing

Comment: @JithuP.S But i guess `httpcore` contains `httpmime`

Comment: @MD i think no,that why its giving me class miss error
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;

Comment: @JithuP.S Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741189/image-uploading-using-multipart-entity-error/29741403#29741403). It has worked for me.

Comment: @Exception i tried your answer also but same issue

Comment: @JithuP.S You got NoclassDefFoundError or duplicate file error?

Comment: @JithuP.S For what purpose are you using these apache libraries?

Comment: @Exception  if i remove the httpmime then only getting the NoclassDefFoundError ,if am using the both libs am getting duplicate error,am using this libs for making header for volley request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78375/discussion-between-jithu-p-s-and-exception).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are missing the flow of build gradle.
As you are trying to use 2 `android {..}` snippet it is not detecting the  2nd one. As a result your exclusion of duplicate meta files are not working.

**Possible solution:**

Just change the order of your build gradle like below:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6"


}
```

**If it still didn't work then check out the following:**

Is it your library build gradle?
I excluded my duplicate meta files from my main projects build gradle. So make sure to exclude the meta files from build gradle of app module rather than library module.

Comment: Did you moved the 'packagingOptions{..}' section in your projects build gradle from your library build gradle. Did you noticed, there are multiple build gradle files in your project.

Comment: Now its ok,i changed the exclude from library to app

Comment: but i have a question,by excluding this files is it make any issues on run-time or it will affect any functionality?

Comment: Nope! Meta-files doesn't affect any programmatic functions of application. Meta files basically contains Textual information like legal-notice, Licences etc of open sources libraries. Excluding it will not affect any thing. In the next Comment I am also going to share why we have exclude it.

Comment: what about  exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' ?

Comment: When we use multiple 3rd party open source libraries, sometimes 2 or more  projects has same named text files (Example: License.txt or Notice.txt or dependencies.txt). That causes the conflict during build time. In that moment our mighty android studio suggest us to exclude those conflicting meta files.

Comment: for me it worked with license.txt and notice.txt in small caps, packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

Comment: @BharatDodeja Yes, it depends on the conflicting file name. Whatever file create conflict in the META-INF directory is needed to be excluded in the packagingOptions