# Map View not working

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi i am a newbie to android development i am trying to integrate map view in my application and it is 
giving the error.I have obtained my api key and have double checked it.
I have pasted my code along with layout file and log file.Can anyone help please.?
Thanks.

```
MainActivity.java

package com.vitarkasolutions.tracker;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;



public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    MapView mapview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapview=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.myMapView);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}



    activity_main.xml

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cordinates "
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Your Location X- and Y- "
             />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cordinates "
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cordinates "
            android:layout_marginRight="46dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/myMapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:apiKey="mymapkey"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </com.google.android.maps.MapView>


    </RelativeLayout>







Logcat
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.vitarkasolutions.tracker/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vitarkasolutions.tracker.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.vitarkasolutions.tracker.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1119)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
04-06 17:56:28.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1798):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

That line should help you:

```
 "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class     "com.vitarkasolutions.tracker.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file     "/data/app/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-    lib/com.vitarkasolutions.tracker-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]"
```

[And here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273218/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-didnt-find-class-on-path)